# Phonegap 3.3 and minSdkVersion=8 becomes minSdkVersion=10

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I've set a minSdkVersion to 8 in www/config.xml :

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="8" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
```

When I run "phonegap local build android", the following files are generated :

```
find /Users/alain/Documents/projects/pg33_3/platforms/android -type d \( -name RCS -o -name CVS -o -name .svn -o -name SCCS \) -prune -o -type f \! -name \*\~ \! -name \*\,v \! -name s.\* \! -name .\#\*  -print0 | xargs -0  grep -n  -e minSdkVersion  /dev/null
/Users/alain/Documents/projects/pg33_3/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:13:    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
/Users/alain/Documents/projects/pg33_3/platforms/android/assets/www/config.xml:26:    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="8" />
/Users/alain/Documents/projects/pg33_3/platforms/android/bin/AndroidManifest.xml:13:    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />/Users/alain/Documents/projects/pg33_3/platforms/android/CordovaLib/AndroidManifest.xml:22:       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
/Users/alain/Documents/projects/pg33_3/platforms/android/CordovaLib/bin/AndroidManifest.xml:22:    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
/Users/alain/Documents/projects/pg33_3/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml:53:    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="8" />
```

So why does it suddenly become minSdkVersion=10 in AndroidManifest.xml and bin/AndroidManifest.xml ?

Here is my config.xml file :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="it.myapp.MyApp" version="1.5.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<name>MyApp</name>
<description>
    My App
</description>
<author email="contact@myapp.it" href="http://myapp.it">
    MyApp Team
</author>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />

<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="8" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
<icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
<icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
<icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
<icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
<icon gap:platform="webos" src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
<icon gap:platform="winphone" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
<icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" />
<gap:splash gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />

<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Could you show me your config.xml file and I should be able to assist further?

Comment: Thank you. I've added it to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems that many of the settings in the config.xml are only used by the Phonegap Build service and get ignored when adding local platforms.

I had the same problem, the only solution I've found is to create a copy of the AndroidManifest.xml and make your changes to it -- then add a hook in the `.cordova/hooks` folder to copy your custom file and overwrite the default one provided by cordova.

You'll probably need this in the long run anyway as you want to customize Android settings that aren't represented in the phonegap config.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You could write some code to make the adjustment, and put it in a hook (as other answers mention).

Here is a Ruby-snippet that should put you on the right track (could use JS or another language too, of course).

```
file_path = root.join("platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(file_path))

# set correct platform requirements
node = doc.css('uses-sdk').first
node['android:minSdkVersion'] = '16'

doc.write_to(File.open(file_path, 'w'))
```